# Dependency Injection... Basic Basic (not injection when new instance)

Tags: java, dependency-injection, code-injection

When I create a new instance by

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
```

the injections never happen.

The example source for MyObject could be...

```
@Stateless
public class MyObject{

    @Inject
    Injection inj;

    public MyObject() {
    }
    ...
}
```

do the injections just work in injected objects? Is there no way of the using injection when I explicitly create a new instance?

I want to create a Class menu that creates instances dynamically (using reflection... the reflection is not the problem... I have tried using the `new` syntax).

I don't want to inject each View class in my menu or main class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injections will only work in objects which the container is controlling the lifetime of. If you are just creating new objects how is the container going to know that the object has been created.

Usually the solution to your problem is one of the following:

- not to create the object yourself, but to ask the container for the object. Although using the container outside of the composition root is a smell you should avoid.
- create the object yourself and inject the dependencies manually. this requires the object creating the new object to have access to all the dependencies the objects it is going to create available at the point of creation. This may not be desirable so you may instead
- delegate the creation to a factory class. This class takes all of the dependencies necessary to create the objects, and the class you are currently 'newing' the object in just has a single dependency on the factory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate the class with @Named so that it is instantiated by the IoC, otherwise it will never get to see the @Inject.

Comment: Indeed it does. On some frameworks for example you would make the class seen from an xml (i.e. applicationContext.xml), but you still need to make the framework aware of that class somehow, and have it instantiate it, instead of using new.